# Faraday's law in Earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

If I throw a conducting coil in air which has N loops wound together and the coils starts rotating or spinning in the mid air, will there be any induced EMF/current in the conducting loops due to Earth's Magnetic field?

A simpler question will be', Does Faraday's law work in Earth's magnetic field?

Comment: This was addressed in Faradays researches in fact, I think the second

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's Laws hold in all magnetic fields.

Theoretically,  there'll be a current. But that will be probably of a very very low magnitude, as the speed required (or the angular velocity required) to produce a current with earth's magnetic field should be quite high.

**Taken from a clearly theoretical view, the experiment would work. From practical viewpoint, one has to do and see.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its an experiment I had to do as an undergrad. Although not throwing in the air but rotating on the desk.

Comment: Would you mind providing your results and conclusions? Provide more information.

Comment: I dont mind but I dont have the protocols anymore. What is the aim/objection in your question?

Comment: No aim/objection, it's a question i have.